# PHP script isnt executing after certain time

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook graph api to get my friends likes and their user information which is available publicly. However I am having a strange problem, my php script which gets all the data through graph api stops after certain number of requests. I hae close to 180 friends and I get the data of 124 friends. After I receive the 124th value, the PHP script neither inserts it in a database nor does it throw an error. It just stops executing. Could timeout be one of the reasons?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is php time out issue you can set your php's execution time by using following line of code at the top of your script

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 100); //300 seconds
```

put as much time you want to execute your php script.

Answer (score 0):

If timeout is the problem means set the maximum execution time `set_time_limit(0);`